# Microservices, CQRS: Eventual consistency vs Strong consistency(Read after Write consistency)

Tags: microservices, cqrs, eventual-consistency

Using CQRS and Event store the choreography between microservices delivers an Eventual consistency where in the changes in one microservice take a bit to propagate to the other downstream systems(essentially other microservices) which are related.
What are the options if the data is so critical that both the microservices should have a strong consistency for the data? One option that i can think of is a write through Cache like a data grid but that would be very fragile specially in a distributed system.

Comment: Give me an example use-case.

Comment: Microservice 1: Managing the interest for a account
Microservice 2: Managing Account
Microservice 2 uses the interest slabs and durations for account management, however any change in any specific Interest Profile will only be available to MS2 in eventual consistency, it may so be happening that any account processing which started after change in one profile could not pick the latest profile since Account Microservice was yet to be updated.

Comment: Do any of the answers provide the solution?

Comment: There is no silver bullet answer to this problem i suppose, it boils down to the CAP theorem and need to be taken on case basis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In such scenario, think about C.A.P. Theorem. According to Wikipedia, "the CAP theorem states that in the presence of a network partition, one has to choose between consistency and availability. Note that consistency, as defined in the CAP theorem, is quite different from the consistency guaranteed in ACID database transactions."

Since you have 2 microservices, so your system definitely needs to be partition tolerant and you are left with either A (Availability) or C (Consistency). If you want to go with C, then your system will suffer in availability terms. When a request comes into Microservice A, then you should not send back a success message to the client until A gets back a response from Microservice B that data has been successfully stored. This way you can achieve consistency by sacrificing availability.

Answer (score 6):

Strong consystency is hard in distributed services and even harder with microservices because they own their data. This means that you can have strong consystency only inside a microservice.

However, you could model the critical operations as a complex process using a [Saga/Process manager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591569.aspx). This means that you use a Saga to orchestrate the completion of the operation in a manner that is acceptable by your business. For example you could use something like the [Reservation pattern](https://www.infoq.com/news/2009/09/reservations)

> This pattern enables managing the resource allocation process in an
>   orderly manner by implementing a two pass protocol - somewhat similar
>   to a two phase commit. During the first pass, the initiator asks each
>   participant to reserve itself. If the initiator gets an OK from all
>   the involved services - within a timeout - it will start the second
>   pass, confirming reservation to all the participants.

Answer (score 2):

in this case whenever any activity start on Account it can fetch the current state from Interest microservice, this way you will always be in sync but you will be making service dependent on each other such that when Interest Service Down , Account service will be effectively down.

Looking down your question, i think what you need to think about is whether consistency is so so important(i am posing this question as when coming from a monolith or transaction background we tent to think that consistency is there).

For eg: lets say if you are placing a Order on amazon and you need to send a customer id , there is a case where you should check whether customer id is valid or not.

this will make Order Service  dependent on Customer Service.

Another solution of this would be while placing a order do not check customer id , but check it on OrderPlace event and take necessary action.

So try to make sure the system better responds to eventualness of state rather than focusing on transaction in microservice. But if yes there are needs which is very very critical to business then make them dependent

Answer (score 0):

Strong consistency can't be achieved in microservices landscape. Once you break down the data store, you are loosing on strong consistency.

In our application we are still to find how to achieve 100% guaranteed eventual consistency, without using any poller/scheduler mechanism to recover from system/network failure.

Answer (score -2):

You may use Kafka or Kinesis to choreograph event consistency between 2 micro services for critical data updates. For example reaction by Micro Service 1 [MS1] to an event triggers appropriate message in a topic which is then read by MS2 instantaneously.

Other benefit of this approach would be that if there are multiple MS dependent on reaction of MS1 then all the other MS' can get that event.

If events are complete and idempotent, then you may enable log compaction as well (not required though) to always get the latest copy over a period of time.

Note: However, make sure to use one partition only within Kafka topic as ordering guarantees in Kafka is per partition only or always add keys to messages so that they land into same partition.

In a nutshell,

1. Kafka / Kinesis as event orchestrator/brokers between microservices
2. Single Partition and/or Messages with Keys (with log compaction)
3. Retention [based on requirements]
4. 3 x Replication [data availability]
5. acks=all [high levels of data consistency]

Comment: How does this offer **strong** consistency?

Comment: This is eventual consistency (Using high performing queues kafka is one such example even AKKA for that sake could be used ).. the question is about achieving Strong consistency however..